# Change multiple values in an XML file to those referenced in another XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a large XML file and I need to change certain values in it where the ID number (OWNINST) matches one in another XML file.

My large XML file 'file1.xml' is in the following format:

```
    <institution>
    <ukprn>1234</ukprn>
    <course>
        <courseID>1</courseID>
        <courseaim>X99</courseaim>
    </course>
    <student>
        <birthdate>30/10/1985</birthdate>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>123456|5</OWNINST>
            <FC>1</FC>
            <STULOAD>100</STULOAD>
            <elq>4</elq>
            <MODE>31</MODE>
        </instance>
    </student>
    <student>
        <birthdate>01/02/1999</birthdate>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>654321|1</OWNINST>
            <FC>2</FC>
            <elq>2</elq>
        </instance>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>654321|2</OWNINST>
            <FC>6</FC>
            <elq>1</elq>
        </instance>
    </student>
</institution>
```

There are multiple students each of which can have multiple instances.

I have another xml file 'File2.xml' which is structured like this:

```
<studentstoamend>
<OWNINST>123456|5</OWNINST><MODE>01</MODE><STULOAD>100</STULOAD>
<OWNINST>111112|1</OWNINST><MODE>31</MODE><STULOAD>75</STULOAD>
</studentstoamend>
```

For each of the students in File2.xml, I would like to change the value of the fields in File1.xml to those listed in File2.xml.  Any students not listed in File2.xml should not be changed.

Please could someone help with this as I don't seem to be able to do it.

This is how far I got:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Student/Instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend/OWNINST]/MODE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, I can run multiple stylesheets to put the data in one node at a time, i.e. update MODE in one stylesheet and MCDATE in another etc

Many thanks

---

Edit: 22/9/2015

Thanks for your help Abel.  It seems to just copy the original file though without making amendments.

Would it help if I could structure file2.xml as follows?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<studentstoamend>
    <student><OWNINST>328352|2</OWNINST><MODE>31</MODE><STULOAD>50</STULOAD><MCDATE>12/01/2015</MCDATE></student>
    <student><OWNINST>652508|3</OWNINST><MODE>01</MODE><STULOAD>100</STULOAD><MCDATE>15/11/2014</MCDATE></student>
</studentstoamend>
```

This is the code I now have

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="students2" select="document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend" />

<xsl:template match="student/instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend/OWNINST]/MODE">
    <xsl:variable name="owninst" select="OWNINST" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$students2[OWNINST = $owninst]/*" mode="file2" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- adjust this, or add more templates in this mode if changes in element names/values are needed -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="file2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="file2" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What part of the last bit of code would I change to target specific nodes, e.g. mode?

Thanks

---

Edit 1:45pm 22/09/15

The output I would like to see is:

```
    <institution>
    <ukprn>1234</ukprn>
    <course>
        <courseID>1</courseID>
        <courseaim>X99</courseaim>
    </course>
    <student>
        <birthdate>30/10/1985</birthdate>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>123456|5</OWNINST>
            <FC>1</FC>
            <STULOAD>100</STULOAD> <!--Updated to 100 (although in this case it already was 100 so no change) -->
            <elq>4</elq>
            <MODE>01</MODE> <!--Updated to 01 -->
        </instance>
    </student>
    <student>
        <birthdate>01/02/1999</birthdate>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>654321|1</OWNINST>
            <FC>2</FC>
            <elq>2</elq>
        </instance>
        <instance>
            <OWNINST>654321|2</OWNINST>
            <FC>6</FC>
            <elq>1</elq>
        </instance>
    </student>
</institution>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep the fields that do not have a corresponding field in the other file (e.g. `<FC>1</FC>` in the first instance of your example)? Or do you want to replace the entire instance?

Comment: I just want to update the fields listed in File2 for that instance.  So, for example in File1.xml OWNINST 123456|5 has a MODE of 31 and a STULOAD of 100.  File2.xml has these as 01 and 100 respectively for that OWNINST so I simply want to amend these values in File1.xml

Comment: I am afraid the rules are still not entirely clear. Will the fields to amend be always these two: MODE  and STULOAD? In other words, can these two names be hard-coded in the stylesheet? Or can the node in File2 contain any mixture of fields? If the latter, is there a list of all possible fields?

Comment: It will always be mode and stuload so they can be hard-coded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it help if I could structure file2.xml as follows?
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <studentstoamend>
>     <student><OWNINST>328352|2</OWNINST><MODE>31</MODE><STULOAD>50</STULOAD><MCDATE>12/01/2015</MCDATE></student>
>     <student><OWNINST>652508|3</OWNINST><MODE>01</MODE><STULOAD>100</STULOAD><MCDATE>15/11/2014</MCDATE></student>
> </studentstoamend>
> ```

Yes, that would make it much more convenient. Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="instance">
    <xsl:variable name="amend" select="document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend/student[OWNINST=current()/OWNINST]"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$amend">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::MODE or self::STULOAD)]"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$amend/MODE | $amend/STULOAD"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks very much michael.hor257k and Abel for all your help.  It still won't let me click the up arrow though.  Sorry that it took a few goes to explain what I wanted but thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="Student/Instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend/OWNINST]/MODE">
> ```

This won't match anything, your input file has `student` and `instance` as element names and XML is case-sensitive.

Inside this template, you apply templates on the original document (File1.xml). To adopt the changes from File2.xml, you will have to apply templates to the second document, something along those lines:

```
<xsl:variable name="students2" select="document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend" />

<xsl:template match="student/instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend/OWNINST]">
    <xsl:variable name="owninst" select="OWNINST" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$students2[OWNINST = $owninst]/*" mode="file2" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- adjust this, or add more templates in this mode if changes in element names/values are needed -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="file2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="file2" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Update: changed the focus of the main template from `MODE` to `OWNINST`.

Comment: Thanks Abel.  I tried this and it just removes all the nodes and leaves just the values (the old, not the new values).

Comment: I've made an edit above to reflect the changes you suggest and the question I have about adjusting the last part.  Thanks Abel, really helpful as always.

Comment: @MartinB, it is not entirely clear what exactly you want output, but the focus of the `student/instance` template was on `MODE`, so it had no `OWNINST` child. I changed that (see update). Depending on what data you want copied from the original file and from the extra file, you will have to make additional adjustments. I tested it, the data is copied now from the extra file.

Comment: @MartinB If you want all data from the original file, plus some of the second file, you can keep the `MODE` in the pattern, but then change the variable `$owninst` to select `../OWNINST`, or add an extra apply-templates in the default mode.