# How do I copy a specific node from another XML document using stylesheets?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>        
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Student/Instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend/STUDENT/OWNINST]/STULOAD">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select=""/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I need to pick up the STULOAD for each OWNINST from file2.xml which is in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<studentstoamend>
    <STUDENT><OWNINST>123456|2</OWNINST><STULOAD>0</STULOAD></STUDENT>
    <STUDENT><OWNINST>654321|1</OWNINST><STULOAD>100</STULOAD></STUDENT>
</studentstoamend>
```

And overwrite the STULOAD for that OWNINST in my file (file1.xml).  File1 has more OWNINST's than file2 and those not referenced in file2 should not be updated.

```
<Institution>
   <Student>
       <Instance>
       <OWNINST>123456|2</OWNINST>
       <STULOAD>3</STULOAD>
       </Instance>
   </Student>
   <Student>
       <Instance>
       <OWNINST>111111|3</OWNINST>
       <STULOAD>18</STULOAD>
       </Instance>
   </Student>
 </Institution>
```

I can't get my copy-of statement to work - if that is the right way to do it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How is this different from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699375/change-multiple-values-in-an-xml-file-to-those-referenced-in-another-xml-file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want to copy from the other document e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Student/Instance[OWNINST = document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend/STUDENT/OWNINST]/STULOAD">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('File2.xml')/studentstoamend/STUDENT[OWNINST = current()/../OWNINST]/STULOAD"/>
</xsl:template>
```